# MySql Count ID that exists in one or more tables

Tags: mysql

I have table user, comment, follow, tip, collection. I need to get all users who registered in January 2016 and did at least one of the activities(tipped at least once, followed someone at least once, created at least one collection, commented at least once) in same period. This is my query:

```
SELECT  distinct u.id FROM user u
where u.id in 
(select distinct t.sender_id from tip t 
WHERE t.date_added>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND t.date_added<'2016-02-01 00:00:00')
or u.id in 
(select distinct c.user_id from collection c 
WHERE c.date_created>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND c.date_created<'2016-02-01 00:00:00')
or u.id in 
(select distinct cc.postedBy_id from comment cc 
WHERE cc.date_posted>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND cc.date_posted<'2016-02-01 00:00:00')
or u.id in 
(select distinct f.follower_id from follow f 
WHERE f.follow_date>='2016-01-01' AND f.follow_date<'2016-02-01')
AND u.date_added>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND u.date_added<'2016-02-01 00:00:00'
```

t.date_added, c.date_created, cc.date_posted,f.follow_date, u.date_added - have type DATETIME. u.date_added - date of register

The query returns all users, whereas I need u.date_added to be January 2016. What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote the query, the date condition only applies within the last `or`:

```
or 
(
    u.id in ()
    AND 
    u.date_added>='...' AND u.date_added<'...'
)
```

(As stated in the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), `AND` takes precedence over `OR`)

You need to make the date condition mandatory:

```
SELECT distinct u.id 
FROM user u
where 
(
    u.id in (
        select distinct t.sender_id from tip t 
        WHERE t.date_added>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND t.date_added<'2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or 
    u.id in (
        select distinct c.user_id from collection c 
        WHERE c.date_created>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND c.date_created<'2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or 
    u.id in (
        select distinct cc.postedBy_id from comment cc 
        WHERE cc.date_posted>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND cc.date_posted<'2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or 
    u.id in (
        select distinct f.follower_id from follow f 
        WHERE f.follow_date>='2016-01-01' AND f.follow_date<'2016-02-01'
    )
)
AND 
u.date_added>='2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND u.date_added<'2016-02-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: i think this is an error, after where clause you enclosed the conditions with () parenthesis and this is not a valid expression

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi, why wouldn't it be valid? I'm just grouping conditions to bypass the default operator precedence

Comment: Try this: `select * from information_schema.PROCESSLIST
WHERE
(
id > 0 OR time >0
)
AND info is null` Same logic applied here

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. So stupid to forget brackets.

Comment: @user5883528, Happy to help

Comment: @AlexTartan my honest mistake, didnt notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use between for cleaner query

```
SELECT  distinct u.id FROM user u
where ( u.id in 
    (
        select distinct t.sender_id from tip t 
        WHERE t.date_added BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or u.id in 
    (   select distinct c.user_id from collection c 
        WHERE c.date_created BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or u.id in 
    (   select distinct cc.postedBy_id from comment cc 
        WHERE cc.date_posted BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
    )
    or u.id in 
    (
        select distinct f.follower_id from follow f 
        WHERE f.follow_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
    ) )
AND u.date_added BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
```